# Please critique my answer regarding Euler's theorem.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> I was working on this problem to decipher a word encrypted using the RSA enciphering system.
> Long story short I had to find a modular exponent:
> $21865^{26767}$$mod$ $46927$

**My Work**
I know that I can use Euler's theorem such that $a^{\phi(m)}$ $\equiv$ $1$ $mod$ $m$ if $gcd(a,m) = 1$.

$\phi(46927)$ = $46480$
So, $21865^{46480}$ $\equiv$ $1$ $mod$ $46927$.

Going back to the original question:
$21865^{26767}$ $mod$ $46927$
= $(21865^{46480})^{\frac{1}{2}}$$*$ $(21865^{3527})$ $mod$ $46927$
= $1$$(21865^{46480})^{\frac{1}{14}}$ $*$ $(21865^{207})$ $mod$ $46927$
= $(1*1)$ $(21865^{46480})^{\frac{1}{280}}$$*$$(21865^{41})$ $mod$ $46927$
= $(21865^{41})$ $mod$ $46927$

I know that the ultimate answer to the question is $5111$ and that I've gone wrong somewhere in the last two lines of this because $(21865^{41})$ $mod$ $46927$ = $4443$. I've checked them on this power mod calculator:
https://www.mtholyoke.edu/courses/quenell/s2003/ma139/js/powermod.html
Can someone please critique my work and tell me where I've gone wrong along the way.

Comment: Taking "roots" are dangerous in modulo arithmetic. I recommend using Chinese Remainder Theorem since you know the factorization of $46927$.

Comment: For a start, you are writing things like $a\mod m=b\mod m$ rather than $a\equiv b\pmod m$. Also you are playing with fractional exponents; not recommended in modular arithmetic.

Comment: What is the motivation to do such a calculation by hand ? Maybe, the chinese remainder theorem makes the task easier, but already to factor this number is not easy by hand. And doing that with a computer, but the rest by hand, would be somewhat inconsequent.